# "ORA-00904: invalid identifier" using CASE statement alias in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not able to filter the result by the alias used for CASE statement.

```
SELECT transfer_order_number, item_number, item_description, requested_qty, received_qty, shipped_qty, 
        CASE 
    WHEN shipped_qty = requested_qty THEN 'Shipped'
    WHEN shipped_qty < requested_qty THEN 'Partially Shipped'
    WHEN shipped_qty = requested_qty AND received_qty < requested_qty THEN 'Shipped and Partially Received'
    WHEN shipped_qty < requested_qty AND received_qty < requested_qty THEN 'Partially Shipped and Partially Received'
    WHEN shipped_qty = requested_qty AND received_qty = requested_qty THEN 'Shipped and Received'
    WHEN shipped_qty IS NULL THEN 'Awaiting Fulfillment'
    END STATUS_TEST
FROM TransferOrder_TABLE
WHERE STATUS_TEST = 'Partially Shipped and Partially Received'
```

I've tried replacing from

```
END STATUS_TEST
```

to

```
END AS "STATUS_TEST"
```

But it didn't help either. I guess the question is, is it even possible to filter the alias used in CASE?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `WHERE` is evaluated before `SELECT`.  So `STATUS_TEST` does not exist when `WHERE` is evaluated, thus the error. https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations/

Comment: Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`. This is processed after the result set is generated and can access aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple option is to use your current query as a CTE, and then filter rows:

```
with temp as
( -- your current query
SELECT transfer_order_number, item_number, item_description, requested_qty, received_qty, shipped_qty, 
        CASE 
    WHEN shipped_qty = requested_qty THEN 'Shipped'
    WHEN shipped_qty < requested_qty THEN 'Partially Shipped'
    WHEN shipped_qty = requested_qty AND received_qty < requested_qty THEN 'Shipped and Partially Received'
    WHEN shipped_qty < requested_qty AND received_qty < requested_qty THEN 'Partially Shipped and Partially Received'
    WHEN shipped_qty = requested_qty AND received_qty = requested_qty THEN 'Shipped and Received'
    WHEN shipped_qty IS NULL THEN 'Awaiting Fulfillment'
    END STATUS_TEST
FROM TransferOrder_TABLE
)
select *
from temp
WHERE STATUS_TEST = 'Partially Shipped and Partially Received'
```